# jQuery hide issue in text overlay on iPad HTML5 video

Tags: jquery, ipad, html, html5-video

The following code is working perfectly on every HTML 5 platform ... except for the iPad.
I just want to "close" the video with a simple click on a div displayed on top of the video itself. If you have an idea on how this could be solved, even without jQuery, it could help a lot. Thanks.

```js
$(function(){
  $("#Xmovie1").tap(function(event){
    $("#Menu1Mov").hide();
    $("#Home").fadeIn('slow');
  });
});
```

```html
<div id = "Home" class="imgHome"><img id = "img1" src ="" alt="home"/>
  <div id = "Menu1Lib" class="cMenu1Lib"></div>
  <div id = "Menu2Lib" class="cMenu2Lib"></div>
</div>
<div id = "Menu1Mov" class="cMenu1Mov" >
  <video id="Menu1Movie" src = "mov.mp4" width="980" height="495" poster = "../medias/img/interface/Poster.jpg" controls></video>
  <div id = "Xmovie1" class = "cXmovie1">x</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tested whether whole event triggers when tapping on "x"? I mean is this a problem in $("#Menu1Mov").hide() or that XMovie1 div element is falsely positioned.

If event triggers, you could try, instead of short-hand: $("#Menu1Mov").css("display", "none") and the same for #Menu1Movie.

If event doesn't even trigger (don't know why this would be the case, but just for sure), then you should trying to redeclare CSS for #Xmovie1, bringing it top for sure, eg. with position:absolute + z-index.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Good point. Events do not trigger at all but z-index do not solve the problem. As I said before, it works on firefox chrome and even ie9. It does not work on iPad (iOs 4.3).

Comment: Update : It is working if I get rid of "controls" attribute in video element. Bad news if it means that I have to build my own controls. Don't really have the time to do so.

Comment: Can't you move the "x" of video element by absolutely positioning it when dealing with iPad?

Comment: Yes, it could be a way to solve the problem, moving the X outside of the video "frame", then it would work... But I can't do that, because the video takes all the available space I have.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add my experience. 
I had the same issue, a div with some labels. Clicking on the div the labels had to toggle. On browsers it was working fine, however on ipad the labels would not hide.

I changed the positioning of labels to absolute and put a z-index and then it started working.